# show 10 line after 10 line in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview with 20 line text in android studio
I want show 0-10 line first in text view 
and set button click for hide 10 line first and show second 10 line in textview.
this work for me but i want hide first 10 line after show second 10 line.

Can you help me?
my Code

```
 btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    InputStream is = getAssets().open("1.xml");
                    int size = is.available();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                    is.read(buffer);
                    is.close();
                    String text = new String(buffer);
                    tv1.setText(text);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    tv1.setText("");
                }
                tv1.setLines(10);
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 i = i + 10;
                 tv1.setLines(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What have you currently done? Post some code what you´ve tried. No homeworkservice.

Comment: maybe you should try using two textviews?

Comment: no i want use for long textview with 1000000 chracter

Answer (score 0):

A easy solution would be to add all the text you want into a ArrayList and you initially load the first ten lines into a StringBuilder and set the TextView's value to the StringBuilder. When ever the button is clicked, add 10 more lines from the ArrayList to the StringBuilder and again set the TextView's value to the StringBuilder. You'll want to enable scrolling on the TextView because it will quickly run out of vertical room to display the 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this - need to add some class variables. after init the lineindex while reading keeps set! you just need to call the `readNextLines()` Method with param `onClick` of your `Button`. But first the `init()` and in the end `close()`.

```
private BufferedReader br;
private FileInputStream fin;
private final String filePath = "...";

private boolean initFile() {
    boolean isCreated = false;
    try {
        fin = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
        isCreated = true; 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Your Message");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Your Message");
    }

    return isCreated;
}

// Don´t forget null check! It´s short version
// pointer keeping it´s position and reading next X lines.
private String readNextLines(int lineCount) {
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while( count < lineCount && this.br.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(br.readLine() + "\n");
        count++;
    }

    return sb.build().toString();
}

private void closeFile() {
    this.br.close();
    this.fin.close();
}
```

#### Maybe add some security and null checks. And maybe it needs some work arounds - it was a fast solution (i´ve got no time, sry)